# Will increasing temperature have an effect to the pH of honey to be able to carry out an acid-base titration?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, titration, temperature

After doing some research on how to decrease the viscosity of honey to undergo acid-base titration with NaOH, one of the ways was by increasing the temperature of honey but the problem is that the pH of honey will decrease so is this true or not? and what is the best way to decrease the viscosity of honey to undergo acid-base titration? (I am comparing acidity of honey from different regions)

Comment: o.O Only reasonable way to do something related to pH, titration and honey would be dissolve a bit it water and titrate the solution. You also seem to be missing the point of titration and that's not the first misguided question on this topic.

Comment: So you mean if I add the same amount of water to all the different kinds of honey would not affect viscosity? also, can you please more specific about the point I'm missing? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Only diluting it may times over would give viscosity  and sugar concentration low enough to talk about titrating it. The point is *why* to do this? I imagine estimating content of carboxylic acids, but for eg. aminoacids may complicate things. Another thing is I'm pretty sure there's some standard procedure to be followed, and you're reinventing wheel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure the volume or mass (depending on the titration approach you are using, you can do it by mass) of undiluted honey that you are titrating. After that, provided that you don't splash any out or loose some by transferring to another container, you can add as much distilled water as you like. It will make no difference to the titration result. Yes, the pH of the sample will be nearer 7, but with a titration you are measuring the amount of the acid or base not the concentration. Once you have the amount, you calculate the original concentration from the volume (the most usual) or mass of the sample, measured before you added any water, indicator or titrant.

You can also do a precise dilution beforehand and measure aliquots out of this. This is quite normal and works for the same reason as above: you are measuring the amount by titration and know what volume or mass of the original sample is contained in your aliquot. I usually prefer to use a good balance rather than volumetric glassware, so pre-diluting does not offer me much advantage, though I think it would generally be the most common non-automated technique.

Adding water will certainly decrease the viscosity, but that is good in that it will allow good mixing of your titrant. I don't think it is at all important that the viscosity is adjusted by the same amount for each honey. That's not what you're measuring by titration.

High heat would wreak all kinds of havoc on your honey, but slight heating would lower the viscosity and increase the reaction rate without negatively affecting your result. I doubt it's worth it though as you can just dilute with distilled water to achieve good mixing. Adding water will also give a clearer solution, which is useful if you are using an indicator not a meter.